# Distributed Cache Files Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-caching

I want to attach different files to different reducers. Is it possible using distributed cache technology in hadoop?

I able to attach the same file(files) to all the reducers. But due to memory constraints, I want to know if I can attach different files to different reducers.

Forgive me if its an ignorant question.

Pls help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a strange desire since any reducer is not bound to a particular node and during the execution a reducer can be run on any node or even nodes (if there is a failure or speculative execution). Therefore all reducers should be homogeneous, the only thing that differs them is data they process.

So I suppose when you say that you want to put different files on different reducers you actually want to put different files on reducer and those files should correspond to the data (keys) those reducers will be processing.

The only one way I know to do it is put your data on HDFS and read it from reducer when it start processing data.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! How to read the data from a reducer? As far as I know, we can read the data from the mapper, i.e., set in the jobconf, the input directory from where data has to be read from hdfs, and pass it on to the reducer, but is there a way to read the data from hdfs directly by the reducer?

Comment: You can use API to read directly from HDFS, here is an example - https://github.com/rystsov/learning-hadoop/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twitter/rystsov/hdfs/SimpleRead.java

Comment: Hi I saw the example in the link.

Comment: I don't know how to use it in my project. Usually, in the JobConf, I use setReducerClass and setMapperClass to specify these classes and setInputPath() for specifying where the mapper has to read the data and setOutputPath() for where the reduce must write the data. But, how can I set in the job conf, so that the reducer will read the data from the hdfs? Please help me!!!

Comment: Just read your data from HDFS (that depends on reducer's key) directly from reducer using FSDataInputStream.

Comment: Hi, I ve posted the code of my reduce class below with FSDataInputStream. I have the FSDataInputStream inside the configure method of the reduce class. The problem I see here is that I have to read the entire record collection and store in the arraylist and in the reduce method, I compare and choose the records that I want with the help of the keys. It will cause out of memory problem. I want to read only the records corresponding to the keys. Is this possible. Please help me!!! Thanks!!! I ve posted my code in the answers below .

Comment: Read data not from configure method, but directly from reduce method, so you'll be able to read needed data since you'll know a key you are processing.

Answer (score 1):

Also it may be worth trying to use an in-memory compute/data grid technology like GridGain, Infinispan, etc... This way you can load your data in memory and you would not have any limits on how to map your computational jobs (map/reduce) to any data using data affinity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will do more research on this!

Comment: Can you tell more about this technology. Is there a way to integrate it with hadoop or I have to start afresh coding in grid gain for the problem I am facing?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.a;

import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class PrefixNew4Reduce4 extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text,   Text, Text>{
//  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


 ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
public void configure(JobConf conf4)
{

    String from = "home/users/mlakshm/haship"; 

    OutputStream dst = null;
    try {
        dst = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(to, false));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /* src (hdfs file) something like hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/home/rystsov/hi                                         */


    FileSystem fs = null;
    try {
        fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(from), conf4);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FSDataInputStream src;
    try {
        src = fs.open(new Path(from));

        String val = src.readLine();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(val);

        al.add(val);


        System.out.println("val:----------------->"+val);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}



    public void reduce (Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {


        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(key.toString());
        String t = stk.nextToken();
        String i = stk.nextToken();
        String j = stk.nextToken();

    ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();

           for(int i = 0; i<al.size(); i++)
            {

                     boolean a = (al.get(i).equals(i)) || (al.get(i).equals(j));

                     if(a==true)
                     {

                         output.collect(key, new Text(al.get(i));                              

                     }


      while(values.hasNext())
          {

             String val = values.next().toString();
             al1.add(val);

      }

for(int i = 0; i<al1.size(); i++)
{
output.collect(key, new Text(al1.get(i));
}
```